# Long to wide data using R

Tags: database, reshape, long-integer, wide-format-data

i'm working on machine learning with R.
I want to import a dataset from excel sheet but to be more easy for me to work on it, i would like to transform my date sorted in multiple row for a same observation .

Here, you'll find a photo of the raw dataset

[RAW DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCTGC.png)

An i would like to get my variables "Hemoglobin, Creatinine, Corrected calcemia, albumin" sorted in columns with one observation (=patient) per row?

Does any one know the right R code to do so?  Impossible to get it works with unstack function

Thank you all

R function unstack and Reshape function from R package reshape2

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.